# Can I specify object sub-indices with a variable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Any way to specify object sub-indices with a variable?

Say I have a function that looks like this

```
function getProperty(property) {
    this.data = {
        name: "john",
        age: 35,
        occupation: {
            title: "coder",
            salary: 60000
        }
    };
    return this.data[property];
}
```

if I want the name I can do

```
getProperty("name");//john
```

but if i wanted, the salary, i can't do

```
getProperty("occupation.salary");
```

because that would try and fetch a property called literally "occupation.salary"

Is there some way to do something like this?

```
getProperty(["occupation"]["salary"]) //60000
```

The point is to be able to take an argument as a single variable and fetch that member of an object, without having parse the argument for a potentially arbitrary depth of sub-indices.

Can this be done?

Comment: There's no built-in facility, but it's easy to write code to do it. There are other questions on the same topic here. In the Java world that's sometimes called "object graph navigation".

Comment: @Pointy if theres a dupe can you point it out?

Comment: you could look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42598589/1447675

Comment: Great, thanks @FelixKling, I knew someone must have asked this before

Comment: There is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference

Comment: I'm really bad at finding duplicates :) Thanks!

Comment: thanks for all the dupes!